# How can I convert HttpResponse<InputStream> to Bitmap format?

Tags: java, android, mobile, bitmap, inputstream

I am trying to convert an `HttpResponse<InputStream>` (a QR code)
to a `Bitmap` object. How can I do that?

```
HttpResponse<InputStream> response =
    Unirest.get("https://unitag-qr-code-generation.p.mashape.com/api?data="+data+"setting="+set)
           .header("X-Mashape-Key", "MY KEY")
           .asBinary();

Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response);
```

Comment: try this one: 
    Drawable.createFromStream(response, "src");

Comment: It is used for java.io.inputstream but this is HttpResponse.inputstream

Comment: Get the `InputStream` out of the `HttpResponse`, by whatever means `HttpResponse` offers (ask whoever wrote `Unirest` how it works). Pass that `InputStream` to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`. Or, stop using `Unirest` and use any of the seemingly infinite number of image-loading libraries available for Android, such as Glide or Picasso.